# "Unreachable code" alert when checking a pointer for "NULL"

Tags: c, static-analysis

I am working on a Linux application written in C which has to pass Polyspace's Code Prover and Bug Finder. I am getting a few "grey" alerts in some functions where I try to check a pointer for NULL.

Here's an example of one of the functions that get the alert:

```
int soc = 0;

static int OpenPort(const char *port)
{
    int ret_status_code = 0;
    struct sockaddr_can sock_addr;
    can_err_mask_t err_mask = (CAN_ERR_TX_TIMEOUT | CAN_ERR_LOSTARB |
        CAN_ERR_CRTL | CAN_ERR_PROT | CAN_ERR_TRX | CAN_ERR_ACK |
        CAN_ERR_BUSOFF | CAN_ERR_BUSERROR | CAN_ERR_RESTARTED);

    soc = socket(AF_CAN, SOCK_RAW | SOCK_NONBLOCK, CAN_RAW);

    if(port == NULL){ /* Grey alert triggers for this line */
        syslog(LOG_ERR | LOG_USER, "NULL pointer passed to function");
        ret_status_code = -1;
    }
    else if(soc < 0){
        syslog(LOG_ERR | LOG_USER, "Can't open socket");
        ret_status_code = -1;

    }else{
        /* Proceed if everything was OK */
    }

    return ret_status_code;
}/*OpenPort*/
```

All functions I have that check a const char *pointer get this alert, but for some reason there are other functions where I check a user-defined struct pointer the same way and only get the alert in one.

The first thing I would like to know is whether someone could please explain to me how does Polyspace check for this alerts (my compiler doesn't seem to identify any unreacheable blocks).

Thank you.

Comment: The `port == NULL` check seems valid, _unless_ the code checker also included all calls of the function and determines it is never called with a null port. The function is static, so all calls are limited to the current coimpilation unit.

Comment: I suggest changing the default value for ret_status_code to -1, then only assign it to 0 when everything is ok.  Also you seem to have one to many '}'

Comment: The *port pointer is provided by the function main(), which in turn collects the contents of a command-line argument to get the actual string name that goes into "port"

Comment: Then it is never called with a null port, which the code checker has determined.

Comment: You need to go through the rest of the code and see the calls to the function `OpenPort`. It is possible that the parameter `port` will never be `NULL`. Still, it may be a good idea to keep the `NULL` check as the code may change in future and the NULL check is always useful

Comment: @RishikeshRaje that's my point, this seems like one of those situations where I don't want the tool to assume anything, it doesn't hurt to have that check.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I will see what happens if I remove the check, but I could swear that this check was implemented some time ago because one of the Polyspace reports was nagging us for not doing it... Still, like I told RishikeshRaje, I would like to keep it.

Comment: @JorgeJuanTorresQuiroga - Even though the tool has identified the part of the code as grey code, you can justify keeping that check as a) it does not cost much and b) it is good defensive coding practice

Comment: Just a test: remove the null check and remove the `static` keyword. I bet the tool will now complain that there is _not_ a null check.

Comment: Personally, I think the `if(port == NULL){...} ` test should be done *before* allocating any resources (and return early). The code as shown could easily cause a file descriptor leak.

Comment: @JorgeJuanTorresQuiroga, "_defensive coding practice_" is only required if pre-conditions cannot be guaranteed. Here, the tool guarantees the pre-condition that port is not null has been met. However, it requires the tool is always run with every modification to ensure the pre-condition is still met.

Comment: @joop thanks for the comment! The function actually checks for this before leaving and makes sure to close the descriptor, but it is done in the bit of code I didn't show. The function is implemented with a single point of return, so several checks are made before leaving, but it doesn't seem to hurt to put the call to "socket" after the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `port == NULL` check seems valid, *unless* the code checker also included all calls of the function and determines it is never called with a null port. The function is static, so all calls are limited to the current compilation unit.

As you say, "the *port pointer is provided by the function main(), which in turn collects the contents of a command-line argument to get the actual string name that goes into "port"."

So apparently the code checker also checked how the function was called and has deermined it is never called with a null port. Then all code after the `port == NULL` branch will not be reached, hence the message.

Note that if the function was not static, the code checker could not make this determination because it doesn't know how the function is called from other compilation units (again, unless it would include all modules and libraries in its analysis...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will check if removing the test works.

Still, I get the same message in another function that is compiled as a shared library, which really confuses me because there are other functions in the same unit that get exactly the same parameter, checked for NULL in the exact same way and only get the "grey" alert in one. 

SHould I write another question with this case or just edit the OP?

Comment: If these other functions are also static, then it doesn't matter if they are in a shared library because these functions can only be called from the current compilation unit and the code checker could also determine they are never called with a null value.

Comment: no, these other functions are part of the library API, they are exclusively called from other modules which are not included in the analysis of the library

Comment: Well, the results of the last report are in, it seems that removing the NULL test did get rid of the alert without generating the opposite one :P I followed the calls to the function and it turns out that we are already checking the command line argument for NULL some lines before copying it to a locally-declared string and passing it to the function, which apparently is safe enough for Polyspace. Thank you very much for the quick and clear responses!

Comment: So you removed the null test. Did you also remove the `static` keyword? You can also test an unsafe call, e.g. call it with a null parameter, and see what the tool tells you. Sometimes it just interesting to learn how a tool "thinks".